# Adding In App Purchases to react native app using expo

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, in-app-purchase

I have a react native app that is using expo. I am trying to implement IAP purchases for IOS. as users sign up to the app. Is it possible to have IAP added to my app whilst my app is configured this way with expo? I have the app setup in my apple developer account as well so I know this isn't the issue.

I cannot get the IAP purchases working within the app and especially with the types from Typescript

I have been getting this error which makes me think this is not possible.

```
ERROR  Error: E_IAP_NOT_AVAILABLE

This error is located at:
    in WrapperComponent (created by withDevTools(WrapperComponent))
    in withDevTools(WrapperComponent)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

This is the current setup that I have for for trying to implement IAP.

.This is the signup page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "../../api/firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import PrimaryButton from "../../components/PrimaryButton/PrimaryButton";
import CustomProgressBar from "../../components/ProgressBar/ProgressBar";
import SecondaryButton from "../../components/SecondaryButton/SecondaryButton";
import { RouterProps } from "../../App";
import { useValidEmail, useValidPassword } from "../../hooks/useAuthHooks";
import { createUser } from "../../api/user";
import { UserProfile } from "../../models/UserProfile";
import { CheckBox } from "react-native-elements";
import {
  PurchaseError,
  RequestSubscription,
  requestSubscription,
  useIAP,
  validateReceiptIos,
} from "react-native-iap";

export type NewUser = {
  uid?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email: string;
};

const PLATFORM = Platform.OS;

const subscriptionSkus = Platform.select({
  ios: ["****"],
});

const SignupScreen = ({ navigation }: RouterProps) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState<"signupOne" | "signupTwo">("signupOne");
  const { email, setEmail, emailIsValid } = useValidEmail("");
  const { password, setPassword, passwordIsValid } = useValidPassword("");
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    password: passwordConfirm,
    setPassword: setPasswordConfirm,
    passwordIsValid: passwordConfirmIsValid,
  } = useValidPassword("");
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState<NewUser>({ email: email });

  const createUserInAuth = async (newUser: NewUser, password: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        FIREBASE_AUTH,
        newUser.email,
        password
      );
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleValidation = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (!newUser.email) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter an Email");
    }

    if (!emailIsValid) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter a valid Email");
    }

    if (!password) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter a Password");
    }

    if (!passwordIsValid) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter a valid Password");
    }

    if (!passwordConfirm) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please confirm your Password");
    }

    if (!passwordConfirmIsValid) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please confirm your valid Password");
    }

    if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Passwords don't match");
    }

    if (!newUser.firstName) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter an First Name");
    }

    if (!newUser.lastName) {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please enter an Last Name");
    }

    setScreen("signupTwo");
    setLoading(false);
    return true;
  };

  const {
    connected,
    subscriptions,
    getSubscriptions,
    currentPurchase,
    finishTransaction,
    purchaseHistory,
    getPurchaseHistory,
  } = useIAP();

  const handleBuySubscription = async (subscriptionId: any) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const purchase = await requestSubscription(subscriptionId as RequestSubscription);
      console.log("Purchase successful:", purchase);
      navigation!.navigate("Signin");
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.warn("Error purchasing:", error.message);
      setLoading(false);
      // Handle purchase failure
    }
  };

  const handleSignUp = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    if (!isChecked && screen === "signupTwo") {
      setLoading(false);
      return alert("Please accept the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy");
    }

    try {
      const response = await createUserInAuth(newUser, password);

      if (newUser.firstName && newUser.lastName && response && subscriptionSkus) {
        const createdUser: UserProfile = {
          uid: response?.user.uid,
          firstName: newUser!.firstName,
          lastName: newUser!.lastName,
          email: email,
        };

        if(PLATFORM === "ios") {
          await handleBuySubscription(subscriptionSkus[0])
        } else if(PLATFORM === "android"){
          return
        }

        await createUser(createdUser)
          .then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
            navigation!.navigate("SignIn");
            console.log("User added to database");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error signing up:", error);
            alert("Sign up failed: " + error.message);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding user: ", error);
    }
  }

  const screens = {
    signupOne: (
      <>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="First name"
          onChangeText={(value) =>
            setNewUser((old) => ({ ...old, firstName: value }))
          }
          value={newUser?.firstName}
          autoCapitalize="words"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Last name"
          onChangeText={(value) =>
            setNewUser((old) => ({ ...old, lastName: value }))
          }
          value={newUser?.lastName}
          autoCapitalize="words"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={(value) => {
            setEmail(value);
            setNewUser((old) => ({ ...old, email: value }));
          }}
          value={email}
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={setPassword}
          value={password}
          secureTextEntry
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={setPasswordConfirm}
          value={passwordConfirm}
          secureTextEntry
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
      </>
    ),
    signupTwo: (
      <>
        <Text style={styles.cost}>Annual cost of $60</Text>
        <View style={[styles.flexed, { width: 300 }]}>
          <CheckBox
            checked={isChecked}
            onPress={() => (isChecked ? setChecked(false) : setChecked(true))}
            containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
          />
          <Text
            style={styles.hereText}
            onPress={() => navigation!.navigate("TermsAndConditions")}
          >
            I accept the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy
          </Text>
        </View>
      </>
    ),
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <CustomProgressBar
          progress={loading ? 1 : screen === "signupOne" ? 0.33 : 0.66}
        />
        <Image
          source={require("../../assets/connection.png")}
          style={styles.logo}
        />
        {screens[screen]}
        {loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        ) : (
          <PrimaryButton
            title={screen === "signupOne" ? "Next" : "Create"}
            onPress={() => {
              screen === "signupOne" ? handleValidation() : handleSignUp();
            }}
          />
        )}
        <SecondaryButton
          title="Back"
          onPress={() => {
            screen === "signupOne"
              ? navigation!.navigate("SignIn")
              : setScreen("signupOne");
          }}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cost: {
    borderColor: "#7FB3D5",
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    marginTop: 10,
    color: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  checkbox: {
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  box: {
    margin: 10,
    marginBottom: 5,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 7,
    shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)",
    shadowOffset: { height: 16, width: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 12,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "mediumseagreen",
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
  specialTag: {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "crimson",
    width: 125,
    padding: 4,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 12,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginBottom: 2,
  },
  flexed: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  hereText: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    color: "blue",
  },
  signupContainer: {
    marginTop: 80,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9",
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 300,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    width: 300,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  errorText: {
    color: "red",
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});

export default SignupScreen;
```

This is the App.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  NavigationProp,
  RouteProp,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "./api/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from "firebase/auth";
import SettingsPage from "./pages/SettingsPage";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import Calculator from "./pages/Calculator";
import ChangePassword from "./pages/ChangePassword";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import UpdateUser from "./pages/UpdateUser";
import HelpPage from "./pages/HelpPage";
import ForgotPassword from "./pages/ForgotPassword"
import PresetValues from "./pages/PresetValues";
// import { InAppUtils } from 'react-native-iap';
import TermsAndConditions from "./pages/auth/TermsAndConditions";
import HomeScreen from "./pages/HomeScreen";
import WorkerPage from "./pages/WorkerPage";
import BayCalculator from "./pages/BayCalculator";
import TeamPage from "./pages/TeamPage";
import LoginScreen from "./pages/auth/Login";
import SignupScreen from "./pages/auth/Signup";
import LoadingScreen from "./pages/Loading";
import { withIAPContext } from "react-native-iap";

AppRegistry.registerComponent("bay-calculator", () => App);

// InAppUtils.ios.consumePurchase('your-subscription-product-id');

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export interface RouterProps {
  navigation?: NavigationProp<any, any>;
  route?: RouteProp<any, any>;
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const InsideStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  
  function InsideLayout({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    return (
      <InsideStack.Navigator>
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="WorkerPage"
          component={WorkerPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="SettingsPage"
          component={SettingsPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="BayCalculator"
          component={BayCalculator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="Calculator"
          component={Calculator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="TeamPage"
          component={TeamPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="ChangePassword"
          component={ChangePassword}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="UpdateUser"
          component={UpdateUser}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="HelpPage"
          component={HelpPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="PresetValues"
          component={PresetValues}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </InsideStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function AuthLayout() {
    return (
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignIn"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignUp"
          component={SignupScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ForgotPassword"
          component={ForgotPassword}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <InsideStack.Screen
          name="TermsAndConditions"
          component={TermsAndConditions}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
        setUser(user);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SignIn">
          {isLoading ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Loading"
              component={LoadingScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          ) : user ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Inside"
              component={InsideLayout}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Auth"
              component={AuthLayout}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default withIAPContext(App)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap/issues/1404)?

Comment: Same here. Are you able to solve?

Comment: @zicxor Im pretty sure it cannot be done with expo build. Must use a Metro tool